# Creating a php file in PHP

Tags: php, superglobals

I'm working on an installer for a project of mine and the installer will create a configuration file.

I have it working 99.99% fine, but in that file i want a check to ensure a hacking can't access it directly, and that code uses the $_SERVER super global, which in every run, gets parsed by php so it breaks the logic I'm trying to go for.

does anyone know I can get the superglobal to stay intact as it is without it parsing or should i rethink my logic and add it elsewhere?

for those who may want to see the code, here it is:

```
#Disable direct access.
if(!strcasecmp(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),basename(__FILE__)) || !defined('accessed')){
    die('<string>No Direct access is allowed for this file.</string>');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Apache (or any .htaccess compatible server), you just have to create a `.htaccess` file in the folder holding your configuration file, containing the following:

```
<Files config.php>
  deny from all
</Files>
```

It will prevent any access to this file through an HTTP request.

See [using .htaccess files](http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.htm) for details.

Comment: this is not a bad idea, though I'm not 100% sure if IIS accepts htaccess files, but i'll note that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use in-script or .htaccess protections - just write the file somewhere outside of the document root. If you don't want something to become available, don't make it available.

Putting it in the document root is like your bank hanging sacks of money in the front window with "do not steal" written on them.

Comment: the problem with that is that this is meant to run on any type of server, so i have to think about apache, iis, etc and also its just foolish to say not to add a clause to prevent access, as you can't hide everything outside the htdoc folder imo.

this is true for some thing but i dont think it is for this